# Android lyout stick buttons together

Tags: android, android-layout, button

Here is my layout

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/image"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ActionButtonText"
        android:background="@drawable/action_button_left"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ActionButtonText"
        android:background="@drawable/action_button_center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ActionButtonText"
        android:background="@drawable/action_button_center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ActionButtonText"
        android:background="@drawable/action_button_right"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>
```

and this is how they look

[image]

What i am trying to do is remove gap between buttons so they look stuck together like this

[image]

I have played with padding and margins but couldn't get it working. How can I achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp" <------ it will work....( minus 10)
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add android:orientation="horizontal" to your LinearLayout