# How show buttons as if they are attached together in android

Tags: android

I want to show the customized buttons as if they are attached. Here is what I got so far:

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
             />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By the above code they are always showing as if there is some gap between them. How can I correct it?

Comment: simply put one to align_RightOf="another_button" in your xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android lyout stick buttons together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515837/android-lyout-stick-buttons-together)

Comment: please paste the btntoggle_selector.xml so that i can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you set the leftMargin to some negative value?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp" //Modify this value to make them as close as possible
    android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
         />
```

Comment: Thanks for all the people and it is started working in different way by modifying one button in linear layout and keeping another in relative layout with marginleft attribute set to -30dp.with that I am facing another problem that anyway I can resolve it:) Thank you once again....